Find a minimal (irregular) boundary over a grid of colored cells
A grid is divided up into red cells (pixels), black cells, and white cells.  We want to find the smallest boundary that:

All red cells are within the boundary
All cells of the boundary itself are white

The boundary can be irregular, but it must be continuous - no gaps or holes.
What algorithm can do this?
What happens if we require the boundary to be convex?
Background: The motivation came from What algorithm can expand find the irregular boundary around a drawing on a printed page?
By continuous I mean that starting from any pixel in the boundary, you can walk to any other pixel in the boundary, while never having to leave the boundary.  By smallest I mean smallest area (though I conjecture it's stronger than that: I conjecture there is a boundary $S$ that any other boundary needs to include.)
(In response to a question:) We can simplify the problem by assuming: All red cells form a single axis-aligned rectangle.

I am suspicious it might be NP-hard, by reduction from the rectilinear Steiner tree problem, but I haven't tried to check whether you can construct such a reduction.

@D.W. An approximate solution would be sufficient: E.g. An algorithm always produces an admissible boundary, which is probably one of the smallest.

I saw a claim that Rectilinear Steiner tree has a PTAS, i.e., is approximable up to any constant factor approximation ratio, so you could try studying those algorithms and seeing if they can be applied to your problem.  For each red pixel, you can do a flood-fill (that covers every pixel that is connected to it by either red or black pixels), and each connected component ("island") then is a vertex in the desired Steiner tree.

@D.W. That's an interesting idea. Would you consider expanding on it to an answer? Especially the parts about flood-fill and finding the connected components?

Thank you for the invitation.  I haven't thought about it enough to have a full answer, and I don't know whether it's possible to build such a reduction.  Hopefully someone else will be able to be of more help.  My apologies.

You want to find a minimum vertex separator that preserves the connectivity of one side. Minimum in the sense that cutting a white vertex costs one, cutting a black or red costs infinite. That means that you in the dual wish to find a simple white cycle that has all red vertices on one side of the cycle. This is definitely fpt in the number of red vertices, but are you after something implementable that runs quickly?

@JohnKemeny Simplicity of implementation is important, even if the results are only probably approximately correct.  Run time performance isn't essential, as long as run time is tractable (eg processing a "typical" image on a typical CPU in a minute or so would be fine).

Are the red cells connected? Or are there few components in the "red graph", i.e. when you ignore all non-red vertices.

@JohnKemeny Edited with more info re red cells.

Oh, but can't you just do a flood fill from the red vertices and not cross the white vertices? The reachable area forms a smallest such area. Perhaps an illustration would clarify the situation?

I gather this is about a two-dimensional grid and imagine axes $x$ and $y$, assume the size of a boundary to be the number of pixels constituting it. What exactly does it mean to walk from one pixel to the next? $x, y$ to $x, y\pm 1$ and to $x\pm 1, y$ I take for granted - can one walk from $x, y$ to $x+1, y+1$?

Either I do not understand your problem, or the problem is solved by using a BFS/DFS from the red cells.  There must be a unique solution if it exists, since if two areas with crossing boundaries exist, you can take the innermost boundaries.
The solution is therefore to run a BFS starting from the red cells, and not crossing over a white cell.
This is the solution when "smallest boundary" means "smallest area" as you have pointed out.  If you rather want the boundary with the fewest possible cells, it corresponds to a minimum cut.
Responding to the comment: in the bfs, initiate the queue with all red vertices. Now, for each new vertex you expand, if it is white, do not add its neighbourhood to the queue.
For simplicity, assume your instance is embedded in an infinitely large black grid. If there is a solution, then the BFS will stop because there exists a separator of white cells that the search cannot cross. Now, whenever you find a solution, the boundary has to be white since if it contained a black vertex the search would not have stopped at that cell, but also added its neighbor (on the outside of the boundary) to the queue.
Here is an illustration where we run BFS from the red rectangle, not crossing white cells.  The yellow cells form the boundary.  As you can imagine, if there were a "white shortcut" through the inside of the boundary, that would form a smaller area and we would choose that instead:


Thanks.  Can you elaborate on what this search will look like? At each red cell, what do you branch on and what do you build up? The boundary must be made of only white cells: it's not clear to me from your answer how you achieve that.

How do you know you'll never need to cross a white cell? How do you know the boundary will be continuous? Perhaps you could write the algorithm in words or pseudocode, and show the invariant and measure of progress.

Any minimal cut in a planar graph corresponds to a simple cycle in the dual.  A simple cycle in the dual is your definition of continuous.

@SRobertJames You don't have to "cross" a white cell because either there is a path around it, or it belongs to the boundary.

@SRobertJames The pseudocode is simply: "run BFS from the red cells, do not expand the white cells".  And then the boundary is defined as all visited nodes that have non-visited neighbors, i.e. the yellow cells in the illustration above.

The reason it produces the boundary with the smallest area is because if you have two solutions $A$ (the boundary and the inside) and $B$ (boundary and inside) that both contain the red squares on its inside, then $A \cap B$ is a smaller solution with the red squares on its inside.

@SRobertJames please consider accepting the answer if it answers your question
